# how to use elastic plugins with jhipster?

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using jhipster with elastic search.
It works quite well with English word search. But for Chinese and Japanese, it splits the word into signal characters.

After some research, I understood this is an elasticsearch issue, and can be solved by plug-in, such as [elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji) and [analysis-smartcn](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-smartcn)

Official site of elastic-search only tells me how to install the plugins with "bin/plugin install ..." I don't think I can run just like this.

It seems, jhipster is using spring-data-elasticsearch to realize the implementation, but I could not find guides on the plugins.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: I don't know exactly but plugins are meant to be installed on the server side only. Spring data is the client here.

Comment: @dadoonet ok, thanks! It do solved part of my puzzle. So...where is my elastic server by jhipster ? Maybe some one can help me with it...

Comment: elasticsearch in JHipster works in 2 ways: in dev, it's embedded in your app and in prod it uses an external cluster. I don"t know if you can use plugins in embedded mode, but you could use an external cluster in dev too.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou many thanks! I will have a look at jhipster docs and see how external clusters works!